# how to compile multiple instances of a source file linking to it different files.o

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, makefile

I have two files.c that contain the same methods(same name and parameters) but implemented differently for provide a approach independent from the implementation. how can I generate a single test file and compile it with both the two implementations without getting deployment errors?

graraphically Explained is:

file_one.c (same method names and parameters of file_two.c)

file_two.c

file_test.c

i want to:

compile -> file_test.c file_one.c

compile -> file_test.c file_two.c

in a makefile without make two copies of file_test.c

---

CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-c -Wall

all: test_matrice test_lista

test_matrice: grafi_test.c grafi_matrice.o

```
       $(CC) grafi_test.c grafi_matrice.o -o test_matrice
```

test_lista: grafi_test.c grafi_liste.o

```
       $(CC) grafi_test.c grafi_liste.o -o test_lista
```

grafi_matrice.o: grafi_matrice.c grafi_matrice.h

```
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) grafi_matrice.c
```

grafi_liste.o: grafi_liste.c grafi_liste.h

```
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) grafi_liste.c
```

clean: rm -rf *.o test_matrice test_lista

---

I get this error:

gcc grafi_test.c grafi_matrice.o -o test_matrice

grafi_test.c:4: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

grafi_test.c: In function ‘main’:

grafi_test.c:21: error: ‘graph’ undeclared (first use in this function)

grafi_test.c:21: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

grafi_test.c:21: error: for each function it appears in.)

grafi_test.c:21: error: ‘G’ undeclared (first use in this function)

make: *** [test_matrice] Error 1

---

Thanks, Giorgio

Comment: Do you mean without making two copies of `file_test.c`, or without making two executables (e.g. `file_test_one` and `file_test_two`)? And would you accept an answer that actually solved your problem?

Comment: i mean  without making two copies of file_test.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
file_test_%: file_test.c file_%.c
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

And if you want you can add a default rule:

```
all: file_test_one file_test_two
```

**EDIT**
The trouble is with your **declarations**. If you have a function like this in `grafi_matrice.c`:

```
void graph(int n)
  {
      ...
  }
```

then code in another file like `grafi_test.c` cannot simply call it. The compiler attempts to compile `grafi_test.c`, reaches the line `graph(3)` and says "*graph()?* I know nothing about this." You must at least have a *declaration* in `grafi_test.c` (above the call) like this:

```
void graph(int);
```

The usual way to handle this is with **header files**, but that can wait.

**EDIT:**
The compiler still knows nothing about `graph`. You must learn about declarations or you will have no chance of success. To start, what does `grafi_matrice.c` say about `graph`?

Comment: i'm doing a similar thing but i get some errors. i think that the compiler don't see some methods used in the test program but defined in the files.o

Comment: CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-c -Wall 

all: test_matrice test_lista 
 
test_matrice: grafi_test.c grafi_matrice.o 
 $(CC) grafi_test.c grafi_matrice.o -o test_matrice 

test_lista: grafi_test.c  grafi_liste.o
 $(CC) grafi_test.c grafi_liste.o -o test_lista

grafi_matrice.o: grafi_matrice.c grafi_matrice.h
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) grafi_matrice.c 

grafi_liste.o: grafi_liste.c grafi_liste.h
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) grafi_liste.c
 
clean:
 rm -rf *.o test_matrice test_lista

Comment: @Buzz, this makefile works for me with C++ (my C is rusty). Can you tell us the error messages?

Comment: gcc grafi_test.c grafi_matrice.o -o test_matrice
grafi_test.c:3: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
grafi_test.c: In function ‘main’:
grafi_test.c:20: error: ‘graph’ undeclared (first use in this function)
grafi_test.c:20: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
grafi_test.c:20: error: for each function it appears in.)
grafi_test.c:20: error: ‘G’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [test_matrice] Error 1

Comment: i posted the makefile and the output in the body of the question so it's more readable :)

Comment: i tried using extern in the test file.. like this: extern graph *new_graph(int n); at the top of the test file but it not worked..

Comment: you told that this kind of problem can be solved with header files but how?

Answer (score 1):

Write a makefile to produce the desired result for file_one.c; duplicate the line that does the compiling, and edit it to use file_two.c AND use a different name for the executable created.

If you provided an example of how you'd create your result for file_one.c, I could be more specific.

Comment: CC=gcc CFLAGS=-c -Wall all: test_matrice test_lista test_matrice: grafi_test.c grafi_matrice.o $(CC) grafi_test.c grafi_matrice.o -o test_matrice test_lista: grafi_test.c grafi_liste.o $(CC) grafi_test.c grafi_liste.o -o test_lista grafi_matrice.o: grafi_matrice.c grafi_matrice.h $(CC) $(CFLAGS) grafi_matrice.c grafi_liste.o: grafi_liste.c grafi_liste.h $(CC) $(CFLAGS) grafi_liste.c clean: rm -rf *.o test_matrice test_lista

Comment: @Buzz: a) W/o any line breaks, that makefile is almost impossible to read (maybe edit it into the original question?), and b) which file(s) need to be replaced to make the second version?